# how to add a ID in my symfony links?

Tags: symfony

i have a question about the linking system in symfony.

I use normal links like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('my_path')}}">click me</a>
```

and then in the controller the corrosponding action looks like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my_path", name="my_path")
 * @Template()
 */
public function myAction()
{ ...
```

now, i have this links in a list and i need to add a `item.id` to each.
so the controller looks like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my_path/id", name="my_path")
 * @Template()
 */
public function myAction($id)
{ ...
```

and all of this is in a loop:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <a href="{{ path('my_path')}}">click me</a> <br>
{% endfor %}
```

**how to add the item.id into the path?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <a href="{{ path('my_path', {'id': item.id})}}">click me</a> <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: but this is the answer and the solution

Comment: It took you exactly 4 minutes to get the answer, next time try to take a deeper look at the documentation before asking.

Comment: yes, sorry but sometimes, when you write a question you look very deep into the problem. and then sometimes you find the answer by yourself very fast